# Отправка нескольких файлов с формы в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ajax

Всем привет.

Есть форма. С нее отправляю через ajax данные, в частности несколько файлов картинок. В форме поле отправки оформлено вот так

```
<input type="file" id="profilepicture" class="profilepicture" name="profilepicture[]" size="25" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" multiple/>
```

то есть тут понятно, что поле позволяет отправить несколько картинок предопределенного формата. Далее в jQuery ловлю данное поле

```
var profilepicture = $('.profilepicture')[0].files[0];
formData.append('profilepicture', profilepicture);
```

и уже action в `functions.php` принимает данные. Сам код обработчика в functions.php идентичен коду из статьи Миши Рудрастого https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/how-to-add-images-to-media-library-from-uploaded-files-programmatically.html
Этот код прекрасно обрабатывает 1 файл и сохраняет его в медиа-библиотеку Wordpress, но с несколькими файлами не работает.
Подскажите, куда двигаться дальше?

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаете только 1-й файл

```
var profilepicture = $('.profilepicture')[0].files[0];
```

Замените на:

```
var profilepicture = $('.profilepicture')[0].files
```